# iScroll Not Loading On A Hashed Link In jQuery Mobile

Tags: html, css, ajax, jquery-mobile, iscroll

I've set up an iScroll on a nested div in one of my detail pages in a jQuery mobile site. Basically what happens is when I click on the button on the main page (for an 'about' page) it goes to the location with a hashed link (using Ajax from what I've gathered). Example:

http://www.example.com/#about.php (this doesn't work with iScroll, BTW this is obviously not a real URL, just an example of syntax)

Basically when I load the URL by itself (as a non-hashed link), the iScroll works fine, but when it's loaded from clicking from the main page the iScroll doesn't load and isn't working. Example:

http://www.example.com/about.php

How do I get the anchor for the `<li>` to link to the direct link and not the hashed link OR is it better to learn how to get the iScroll javascript to load in the Ajax loaded link? Thanks for the help.

### UPDATE:

Here's the syntax I've used for the listview that I have linked to the about page. It's the basic listview syntax that I've seen used everywhere I've read up on it. All I'm dealing with is the fifth link right now (ABOUT). I'm not using a hash in the anchor and yet it still links it to a hashed location. What's interesting is that it's not http://www.example.com/index.php#about.php it's just http://www.example.com/#about.php.

```
<ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="#nav1">TEST</a></li>
        <li><a href="#nav1">TEST 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#nav1">TEST 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#nav1">TEST 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">ABOUT</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: I would definitely learn how to work with the jQuery Mobile framework if you plan to use it in the future. This issue can be resolved with event delegation and binding to the custom jQuery Mobile page events.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose I'm still wrapping my head around the functionality of it all. I obviously want to use Ajax because of the smooth transitions, etc.

Comment: Be careful with the transitions. They can look pretty bad on Android devices. This is the focus of the jQuery Mobile team right now, to smooth-out transitions (and to get real fixed headers/footers): http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/01/10/upcoming-releases-1-0-1-1-1-and-beyond/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are binding the iScroll initialization within a `document.ready` handler. If this is the case then you need to change that to a delegated event handler (this is standard jQuery Mobile practice):

```
$(document).delegate('#about-page-id', 'pageinit', function () {
    var myScroll = new iScroll('id-of-element');
});
```

> ## Important: Use pageInit(), not $(document).ready()
>
> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the
>   $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the
>   DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the
>   contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready
>   handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a
>   new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event.
>   This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page.

*Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html*

Long story made short: jQuery Mobile uses AJAX to pull new pages into the DOM, this has a number of side-affects.

1. All IDs must be unique site-wide since multiple pages can be in the DOM at once.
2. When linking to an external page (`<a href="about.html">About</a>`) only the `data-role="page"` element and its descendants will be grabbed (everything else will be ignored).
3. You cannot rely on `$(document).ready()` because pages grabbed through AJAX do not fire this event, they fire `page events` as specified here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html

If you want to force a reload when linking to another page there are several options:

1. Put `rel="external" on the link tag:``
2. Put `data-ajax="false"` on the link tag:  `<a data-ajax="false" href="about.html"></a>`
3. Globally disable AJAX handling of links: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html

But note that using any of these methods will disable transitions.

**UPDATE**

If you are getting hashed links that means that either you turned off the `historyPushState` functionality or you are using an old version of jQuery Mobile. If you are using an old version I highly reccommend upgrading to 1.0 (there are lots of performance increases in 1.0 RC3 and 1.0 Final): http://jquerymobile.com/download/

Comment: I'm using 1.0 already so I don't believe that's the issue. I just added code above for my listeview. The iScroll initalization isn't being used in document.ready either it's simply: <script type="text/javascript">
      var myScroll;
      function loaded() {
   myScroll = new iScroll('content_bg');
      }
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
      </script> . Does that make sense?

Comment: @MxmastaMills I didn't think using an old version was your problem, that was just a welfare check to make sure you aren't using a really old version. If you aren't leveraging jQuery Mobile page events with `.delegate()` then you need to change your code (this is how it is done in jQuery Mobile). Basically you are running your code when the page loads (the `window.load` event) which only happens on the first page load, each subsequent jQuery Mobile page load won't run your code unless you put it in an event handler like my example.

Comment: Ah ok, yeah that makes sense. Thanks for helping out, this is a great point in the right direction.

Comment: Glad to help, if you need more assistance I have answered quite a number of jQuery Mobile questions on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:752738+[jquery-mobile]

Comment: I'm assuming the event handler code would go in the <head> tags of the main page since it's referencing '#about.php' in the code? I've tried it in both places and I see exactly what you're saying (that it's basically one document being loaded once so you have to call event handlers for separate views) but for some reason it's not working correctly. I've tried it in the head tags of the about page as well. It doesn't seem to make sense that it wouldn't work now...

Comment: A couple things. **1.** The location of the code is somewhat unimportant; at the end of the body tag is my favorite spot because it allows the page to render faster without JS evaluation blocking the rendering process. **2** That being said, you should package all of the JS for your site into a single include file and include it in each page (as long as you don't put the include inside a `data-role="page"` element it will be ignored except for the first page-load). **3** Make sure you are binding to the ID of the `data-role="page"` element and not the name of the PHP page in which it lives.

Comment: Ok great. I got it to work. One thing to mention is that once I get entered correctly, it didn't work on the iOS Simulator (from XCode) but worked when I uploaded it to the server and tested it on my iPhone. (I'm taking it one step at a time and understand that Android and Blackberry could create some problems for me but I'm new to this.)