# Jquery Mobile Android App - Fixed headers multiple pages?

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

Does anyone know a good way to fix a header div (`.headerArea`) on each page using Jquery or CSS with a scrollable area beneath?

Cant find anything that works!

Cheers
Paul

Comment: In the newest versions of the Android browser, the CSS property position:fixed should finally be [available](http://caniuse.com/css-fixed). It's probably not a production-ready solution, but it is something worth keeping in mind.

Answer (score 0):

There are several JavaScript scrollers out there that will help mimic native scrolling.

jQuery Mobile's scrollview experiment is optimized for the 1.0 Final release: http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/

iScroll has a newish version (4): http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Flexscroll's primary function is to create custom scrollbars but it also works in a touch environment: http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar

They are all pretty light-weight, 15-20KB minified.

Here is a basic example of using the jQuery Mobile Scrollview Experiment: http://jsfiddle.net/NX8SN/

Comment: but you will have native scrolling and any of the plugins running next to each other, So a lot of times you end up pulling down the header bar with native scrolling when you actually want to scroll the content section. No matter which scroller you take, make sure the scrollable element covers the whole screen to avoid this from happening.

Comment: cheers for your help guys, i've had a go with iscroll, but struggling to get it to work on multiple screens!
cheers

Comment: @frequent Your issue is a CSS one. The native scroll-bar only comes into play when the content of the page is more than 100% of the viewport's height. Setting `max-height : 100%` and `overflow : hidden` on the `data-role="page"` elements will make sure that native scroll-bars don't appear. With iScroll (I saw your other questions) you need to setup the layout of your page so the header is at the top, footer the bottom , and content area is everywhere else (not touching the top or bottom of the page). These CSS issues are taken care of with jQuery Mobile's Scrollview Experiment automatically.

Comment: Multiple jquery mobile screens I meant by the way, as all the pages are in the same page i'm struggling tbh..

Comment: @Paul This answer may help you to get it working on multiple pages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841427/iscroll-not-loading-on-a-hashed-link-in-jquery-mobile/8841495#8841495

Comment: Cheers Jasper - each page does now just contain header and wrapper divs.

Comment: @jasper - cheers for that - i'll work my way through that example!

Comment: Another potential solution is Joe Hewitt's [Scrollability](http://joehewitt.github.com/scrollability/). Please note that it does **NOT** work out of the box on Android. However, I felt that out of all the options that were available, the scrolling felt the smoothest and most native (imho, as of 6 months ago). It's not too difficult to hack it to work for Android as well, which is what I did on my last mobile project.